# WPF TabControl : Setting the initial tab to load automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm setting a view to `TabRegion`:

```
_mainView = _container.Resolve<MainContent>();
_mainRegion.Add(_mainView, "MainContent");
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.TabRegion,
                                        () => _container.Resolve<StrategyList>());
```

The region loads, but I still have to click the actual tab for the view to load. What do I need to do to have the view loaded in the first tab automatically without the need to click the tab itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to activate it.

`IRegion.Activate(view)`

Comment: I must be missing something `_mainRegion.Activate(_tabView);` throws an error that "the region does not contain the specified view".

Comment: You need call active on the region that contains the tabitem. You're activating the new tabitem view you just put in the region.